# Dynamic table in Dart: tbody td's don't align with thead td's

Tags: html, css, dart

Background: I'm working in Dart, making an application both client and server side; this application co-works with a MongoDb database, uploading/downloading data to fill some HTML elements.

I have a table inside a div (to display and hide it on some events).

HTML

```
<div id="divShowTable">
    <table id="tabShow">

      <thead id="theadShow">     
      </thead>

      <tbody id="tbodyShow">
      </tbody>

    </table>

  <button id="btnBack">Back</button>
  <button id="btnNew">New record</button>

</div>
```

I have a Dart code that fills the `<thead>` with the keys of the fields of the mongoDb collection (dynamically chosen, epends on the collection you want).

```
void fillTable(List<Map> lista) {
  Map m = new Map();
  m = lista[0];
  List<String> lk = new List<String>();
  lk = m.keys;

  /* Delete old titles */  
  tabellaShow.tHead.innerHtml = '';
  TableRowElement trh = tabellaShow.tHead.addRow();
  for (int k = 1; k < lk.length; k++) {
      TableCellElement tch = trh.addCell();
      tch.innerHtml=lk.elementAt(k);
    }

  /* Delete old td's */
  tabellaShow.tBodies[0].innerHtml = '';

  for (int k = 0; k < lista.length; k++) {
    m = new Map();
    m = lista[k];

    TableRowElement tr = tabellaShow.tBodies[0].addRow();
    tr.id = 'rigaShow';
    for (int j = 1; j < lk.length; j++) {
      TableCellElement tc = tr.addCell();

      if (m[lk.elementAt(j)] != null && m[lk.elementAt(j)] != 'null')
        tc.innerHtml = m[lk.elementAt(j)]; else tc.innerHtml = '';
    }
  }
}
```

Yes I have the `TableElement`, there are no errors.
For cycles start from 1 to ignore the `_id` field automatically set by MongoDb.
This code, depending on the `List<Map>` you give, dinamically update and show the table related to that list.

I have 4 possibilities:

1) Show a table with 10 fields.

2) Show a table with 3 fields.

3) Show a table with 2 fields.

4) Show a table with 1 field.

I set a width to the td's (of thead and tbody) to 100px, and the last child of thead to 116px (due to a scrollbar I need), but it isn't respected.

Well, for the tables 2, 3, 4 it's all ok (visually you don't see the td's are not aligned), but the table 1 is very very ugly to see, td's go where they want with the width they want.

I tried applying the width property from Dart, from CSS, tried different `display` values, but nothing works.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You should consider using polymer/angular and use a model, that automatically updates the view.

Comment: A table will always align all its TDs so maybe something's inserted wrong?

Comment: I'll try looking at polymer and angular, I'm trying to do everything in normal Dart. It is impossible that something is inserted wrong, else I'd have problems in the other 3 tables.

Comment: Can you maybe post a complete example, or upload the project to github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved removing this in the .css:

```
#tbodyShow, theadShow tr{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: @Robert        found the solution. Still thanks for your help.